# Js - if var is undefinied

Tags: javascript

Why doesn't an alert show in the below code?

```
var a = Array();
a[1] = "asd";
a[100] = "asdd";
alert(typeof a[50]);
if(typeof a[50] === 'undefinied') alert('und');
```

Comment: You have a typo in `undefinied`

Comment: ...and in your question title.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`undefinied` should be `undefined`.